# Find named pipe associated with my IIS application

Tags: powershell, iis-7, named-pipes

I have an IIS application with a named pipe binding. When I open powershell and run `Get-ChildItem '\\.\pipe\'`, I see a long list of named pipes with crazy names like GUIDs. Some of them start with iisipm which I assume means they are created by IIS. How can I programmatically determine which one these pipes is associated with my IIS application?

Comment: While do you want that? Anyway you can get the worker processes of a pool via IIS related cmdlets, and then by reading the process arguments of the processes you know the named pipe information.

Comment: @LexLi I need to add permissions to a particular named pipe after it's been created but don't know which one needs the new rights.

Answer (score 1):

A named pipe is just a file on the filesystem used for I/O through SMB.  What you're asking is anlogous to saying, "I have a file on my desktop, what is using it?!"  I will give you that your question is slightly more abstract because there are built-in ways to figure out read/writes to normal files via SACLs on Security Descriptors and using the Security event log.  And while this can still be done with named pipes, you'd have to add a SACL to every named pipe and ensure proper auditing was turned on to catch this.

In this case, the easiest way to accomplish what you're looking for is to use Process Explorer to find all open handles to named pipes and find the IIS worker process that has a handle for it.

To do this:

1. Run Process Explorer, as admin
2. Press, CTRL-F for Find
3. Select, "File Handle or DLL..."
4. Type, "\Device\NamedPipe\"

..and identify which process is your IIS process and then which pipe it has a handle open to.

Edit:  Handle.exe (also from Sysinternals) should also provide this information.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't accept this because I need to find it programmatically. Do you think it would be more fruitful to ask how to grant named pipe write permissions for an IIS website to a particular user?

Comment: handle.exe outputs to STDOUT -- if you're not going to code down to the Windows API to enumerate the handles for a file, then you need to stand on the shoulder's of giants (in this case, Mark Russinovich).  get your iis PID, pass to handle.exe, find your pipe -- this can definitely be done programmatically:  handle.exe -a -p pid-number